# Is there an easy way to take the output of print_r or var_dump and convert it to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to take the output of a var_dump or print_r and convert it to an array that mirrors what was in the original.

convert this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [title] => Edison's Friends
    [status] => 1

    [field_deck_owner] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 15
                        )

                )

        )

    [name] => Mack
)
```

to this:

```
$array =  array(
    'title' -> 'Edison's Friends',
    'status' -> '1',
    'field_deck_owner' = array (
        array(
            array (
                'uid'->15
                )
            )
        ),
    'name' = "Mack"

);
```

Are there scripts that do this?  A javascript site ;-)  Something?

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I want to input the text and then have it parse our the ascii version of the array.  I want to be able to manually edit the values.

Comment: I'm going to close this.  I found what I need.  It's var_export.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a parser like you're asking for, but if you just want an array of the object's properties you can just [cast it to an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) directly.

Comment: I found what I need. It's var_export(). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ummmm just set it equal..

If you **are** doing this:

```
var_dump($something);
```

**SO DO:**

```
$something_else = $something;
```

And viola! you now have a copy.

---

### Update:

Actually you can try this: [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
var_dump($something);
```

**SO DO:**

```
$something_else = get_object_vars($something);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way nor built-in PHP function to do that. Use [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the code of any JSON class parser written in PHP for this sintaxis, seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is really just a StdClass then cast it to an array

$array = (array)$object;

If the object has protected or private properties you might get undesirable results (null bytes in property names).  In that case I would look at for public only properties

$array = get_object_vars($object)

Answer (score 0):

i use this function :

```
function std_class_object_to_array($stdclassobject) 
{ 
    $_array = is_object($stdclassobject) ? get_object_vars($stdclassobject) :   $stdclassobject;
    foreach ($_array as $key => $value)  
    { 
        $value = (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) ? std_class_object_to_array($value) : $value; $array[$key] = $value;  
    } 
    return $array; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to reverse a print_r of a stdClass or a Array.

You just have to use the reversePrint_r function, it expects the first parameter to be a split of the print_r output, the second parameter is the index of the first variable of the print_r output, note that you can't put directly the index because is a referenced parameter, and the third parameter indicates if is an array or a stdObject.

```
function reversePrint_r($stringObject, &$index, $isArray) {
        $result = ($isArray) ? array () : new stdClass ();
        $continue = true;
        $numberSpacesOriginal = ((preg_match_all ( "/ +/", $stringObject [$index], $matches )) ? strlen ( $matches [0] [0] ) : 0);
        while ( $continue ) {
            $line = $stringObject [$index];
            $numberSpaces = ((preg_match_all ( "/ +/", $line, $matches )) ? strlen ( $matches [0] [0] ) : 0);
            if ((preg_match ( "/Array$/", $line )) || (preg_match ( "/stdClass Object$/", $line ))) {
                $isNextArray = (preg_match ( "/Array$/", $line )) ? true : false;
                $var_name = getVariableNameFromLine ( $line );
                $index += 2;
                $parameter = getListFromStdClass ( $stringObject, $index, $isNextArray );
                addResult ( $result, $var_name, $parameter, $isArray );
                $index ++;
            } else {
                $var_name = getVariableNameFromLine ( $line );
                $parameter = getParameterFromLine ( $line );
                addResult ( $result, $var_name, $parameter, $isArray );
            }
            $index ++;
            $numberSpaces = ((preg_match_all ( "/ +/", $stringObject [$index], $matches )) ? strlen ( $matches [0] [0] ) : 0);
            if ($numberSpaces != $numberSpacesOriginal) {
                $continue = false;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

function addResult(&$result, $key, $value, $isArray) {
    if (! $isArray) {
        $result = ( object ) array_merge ( ( array ) $result, array (
                $key => $value 
        ) );
    } else {
        $result [$key] = $value;
    }
}

function getVariableNameFromLine($line) {
    $result = split ( preg_quote ( "=>" ), $line );
    $result = preg_replace ( "/( *\[|\] *)/", "", $result [0] );
    return $result;
}

function getParameterFromLine($line) {
    $result = preg_replace ( "/^.*=> /", "", $line );
    $result = preg_replace("/\n/","",$result);
    return $result;
}
```